# How to upload file by PHP cURL using ftp connection?

Tags: php, curl

I am using this script to upload myfile by curl function and ftp connection.

In local it works fine but in my server file is appeared uploaded but it have zero file size.

what is wrong? Thank You.

```
$ch = curl_init();
$localfile = (dirname(__FILE__).'/asset/myfile.zip');
$fp = fopen($localfile, 'r');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "ftp://$user_name:$user_pass@$server/".'myfile.zip');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_UPLOAD, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_INFILE, $fp);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_INFILESIZE, filesize($localfile));
curl_exec ($ch);
curl_close ($ch);
```

and also how can I upload multiple files in this script like:

```
$localfile1 = (dirname(__FILE__).'/asset/myfile1.zip');
$localfile2 = (dirname(__FILE__).'/asset/myfile2.zip');
$localfile3 = (dirname(__FILE__).'/asset/myfile3.zip');
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To upload the file in curl you can use the [curl_file_create](http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-file-create.php).Try the below one:

```
$localfile = (dirname(__FILE__).'/asset/myfile.zip');
$curl_file = curl_file_create($localfile,'zip');
$params = ['file' => $curl_file];

$ch = curl_init();
$localfile = (dirname(__FILE__).'/asset/myfile.zip');
$fp = fopen($localfile, 'r');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "ftp://$user_name:$user_pass@$server/".'myfile.zip');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_UPLOAD, 1);
//curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_INFILE, $fp);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $params);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_INFILESIZE, filesize($localfile));
curl_exec ($ch);
curl_close ($ch);
```

Answer (score 3):

This source may helps your problem.

http://www.web-development-blog.com/archives/tutorial-ftp-upload-via-curl/